On limit of $\frac{\sqrt[3]{1-x^7}}{\sqrt[7]{1-x^3}}$ as $x\to 1$
I did it as follows
$$\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1-x^7}}{\sqrt[7]{1-x^3}}=\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{1-x^7}{1-x^3}\dfrac{\sqrt[7]{(1-x^3)^6}}{\sqrt[3]{(1-x^7)^2}}$$
$$=\dfrac{7}{3}\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{\sqrt[7]{(1-x^3)^2}}{\sqrt[3]{(1-x^7)^2}}{\sqrt[7]{(1-x^3)^4}} $$
$$=\dfrac{7}{3}\left(\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{\sqrt[7]{1-x^3}}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^7}}\right)^2\lim_{x\to1} \sqrt[7]{(1-x^3)^4}=0$$
But I feel it is wrong. Any suggestions please

why did you conclude the limit is $0$?

Hint: prove $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1-x^a}{1-x}=a$, so $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{(1-x^a)^{1/b}/(1-x^c)^{1/d}}{(1-x)^{1/b-1/d}}=\frac{a^{1/b}}{c^{1/d}}.$

Substitute x = 1-h, x^7 = 1 - 7h + 28h^2..., 1 - x^7 ≈ 7h.

Certainly not the most elegant approach, but it works:
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt[3]{1-x^7}}{\sqrt[7]{1-x^3}} = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt[21]{(1-x^7)^7}}{\sqrt[21]{(1-x^3)^3}} = \sqrt[21]{\lim_{x\to 1} {\frac{(1-x^7)^7}{(1-x^3)^3}}} = \sqrt[21]{\lim_{x\to 1} {\frac{(1-x)^7(1+x+x^2 +x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^7}{(1-x)^3(1+x+x^2)^3}}} = \sqrt[21]{\lim_{x\to 1} (1-x)^4 {\frac{(1+x+x^2 +x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^7}{(1+x+x^2)^3}}} = 0$$
EDIT: the main flaw in your approach is that you still have $1-x$ in the denominator when you conclude, but there's no reason to believe that limit is $0$. What I did was to rewrite the function in a way which allowed me to use the fact that the limit of a product  is the product of the limits, where one of them is definitely bounded (and the denominator does not vanish as $x \to 1$) and the other one approaches $0$.

I feel better now. Thanks

A rough solution. When we substitude 1, it's clear that we get 0/0 so we can't simply plug numbers in. We need to make a few assumptions that are valid but will simply make solving the problem easier. For starters, we can make say that $1-x^7$ will be approximately $7(1-x)$ as $x$ approaches $1$. The same is true for $1-x^3$ will be approximately $3(1-x)$. So rewriting this fraction for the approximation is $\lim_{x \to 1}$ $\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{7(1-x)}}{\sqrt[7]{3(1-x)}}$ we achieve $\lim_{x \to 1}$ $\dfrac{7^{1/3}{(1-x)^{1/3}}}{3^{1/7}{(1-x)^{1/7}}}$. This is then simplified to $\lim_{x \to 1}$ $\dfrac{7^{1/3}}{3^{1/7}}$⋅$(1-x)^{4/{21}}$. This clearly evaluates to 0, so the answer should be 0.

Another way by $y=1-x\to 0$
$$\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1-x^7}}{\sqrt[7]{1-x^3}}=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{7y+o(y)}}{\sqrt[7]{3y+o(y)}}=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{y}}{\sqrt[7]{y}}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{7+o(1)}}{\sqrt[7]{3+o(1)}}$$
and all reduces to solve
$$\lim_{y\to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{y}}{\sqrt[7]{y}}=\lim_{y\to 0}\sqrt[21]{y^4}$$

This is the best way. Shift the limit to the origin, then use whatever expansion we have.

@QuýNhân I don't know wheter or not this is the best method but Shifting to the origin very often makes things clearer!

The typical way to handle limit of algebraic functions is to use the formula $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^n-a^n} {x-a} =na^{n-1}\tag{1}$$ and here we use the formula with $a=1$ and different values of $n$.
We can write the expression under limit as $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt[3]{1-x}}{\sqrt[7]{1-x}}\cdot\sqrt[7]{\frac{1-x}{1-x^3}}$$ The first factor tends to $\sqrt[3]{7}$, last factor tends to $1/\sqrt[7]{3}$ and the second factor is $(1-x)^{4/21}$ which tends to $0$. The desired limit is thus $0$.


On limit of $\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1-x^7}}{\sqrt[7]{1-x^3}}$ as $x\to 1$

Alternative approach:
I am on thin ice here.  The following approach is very off-beat (from my perspective).  However, I can find no flaw in the logic.
Lemma-1 
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1 - x^7}{1 - x^3} = \frac{7}{3}.$ 
Proof
Since the fraction evaluates to $~\dfrac{0}{0},~$ you can use  L'Hopital's rule. 
Taking the derivative of the numerator and denominator, gives 
$\displaystyle \frac{-7x^6}{-3x^2} = \frac{7}{3} x^4.$
Lemma-2
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1} \left[ ~\frac{1 - x^7}{1 - x^3} ~\right]^3~$ is finite. 
Proof
From Lemma-1, there exists finite $~L~$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1 - x^7}{1 - x^3} = L.$ 
Since $~L~$ is finite, so is $~L^3.$

To demonstrate that the original expression has a limit of $~0,~$ it is sufficient to demonstrate that the original expression, taken to the $~21$-st power, has a limit of $~0.$
Taking both the numerator and denominator to the $~21$-st power gives the fraction
$$\frac{(1 - x^7)^7}{(1 - x^3)^3} = \left[ ~\frac{1 - x^7}{1 - x^3} ~\right]^3 \times (1 - x^7)^4. \tag1 $$
The RHS of (1) above has two factors.  By Lemma-2, the first factor has a finite limit.  Clearly, the 2nd factor, $~(1 - x^7)^4~$ has a limit of $~0,~$ as $~x \to 1.$  So, you end up with
$$\text{a finite number} ~\times 0.$$
